# Codecetion Stub testing static method

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, codeception

I have class:

```
class Subscribe
{
    public static function isSubscribe($email)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My test:

```
    public static  function testIsSubscribe()
{
    $subscribe = new \Model\Subscribe();
    $object = Stub::make($subscribe, ['isSubscribe' => 'isSubscribe']);
    $this->assertEquals('isSubscribe', $object->isSubscribe(['email' => 'email@gmail.com']));
}
```

But, testing static class `testIsSubscribe()` give me exception

> PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_BadMethodCallException:

Comment: you have a misspelling in class name. Subsribe != Subscribe

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but it is still not the case. Article in https://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html, But not work phpunit v. 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are not tested, they should avoid writing